# django modelformset_factory doesn't include actual forms

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I've been trying to follow tutorials and other SO questions and have a `modelformset_factory` that's displaying a list of what looks like forms in the html, but it turns out they're not actual forms.

html that gets displayed:

```
<div ='container'>

        <div class='row'><tr><th><label for="id_form-0-config_key">Config key:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-0-config_key" maxlength="63" name="form-0-config_key" type="text" value="ClientMustVerify" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-0-config_value">Config value:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-0-config_value" maxlength="63" name="form-0-config_value" type="text" value="TRUE" /><input id="id_form-0-id" name="form-0-id" type="hidden" value="3" /></td></tr> <input type="submit" value="Update" /></div>

        <div class='row'><tr><th><label for="id_form-1-config_key">Config key:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-1-config_key" maxlength="63" name="form-1-config_key" type="text" value="Auditing" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-1-config_value">Config value:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-1-config_value" maxlength="63" name="form-1-config_value" type="text" value="FALSE" /><input id="id_form-1-id" name="form-1-id" type="hidden" value="4" /></td></tr> <input type="submit" value="Update" /></div>

    <div>
```

notice there is no `form` tag anywhere.  working backwards, here's the excerpt from the template:

```
<div ='container'>
    {% for form in formset %}
        <div class='row'>{{form}} <input type="submit" value="Update" /></div>
    {% endfor %}
<div>
```

yes, I added the `submit` button manually hoping to get these to work, but of course if there isn't a `form` tag, then the `submit` button won't do anything.
views.py:

```
from limbo.models import serverConfig
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.forms import formset_factory

def editServer(request):
    result = serverConfig.objects.values()
    myConfigs = [entry for entry in result]

    finalFormSet = modelformset_factory(serverConfig, exclude=('id',), extra=0)
#other lines
    return render(request, 'limboHtml/ServerConfiguration.html', {'formset': finalFormSet, 'SubmitMessage': '', 'CurrentConfigs': myConfigs})
```

forms.py:

```
class serverForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = serverConfig
        fields = ['config_key', 'config_value']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(serverForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            self.fields['config_key'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['config_key'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

and models.py:

```
class serverConfig(models.Model):

    config_key = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    config_value = models.CharField(max_length=63)
```

I tried using `finalFormSet = formset_factory(serverForm, extra=0)` at one point, but then I just got no content in the html...

Comment: at this point, I'm just manually adding `<form method="post" >{% csrf_token %}` before `{{form}}` and then `</form>`, but was hoping for a more built-in way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [formset documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates) you must add the form tag manually. This is not very different from what you do when displaying a single form.

It appears that you are iterating through the formset and displayig them one by one. That means you must also add the management form

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <div ='container'>
        {% for form in formset %}
            <div class='row'>{{form}} <input type="submit" value="Update" /></div>
        {% endfor %}
    <div>
</form>
```

Or you will get errors about a missing or misconfigured management form.

Comment: thanks, evidently i missed that part of the docs.  I had seen it displaying the form tag and submit automatically with a simpler form, so I'd assumed (always bad) this would be similar.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that it does not include the  tags, or a submit button. We’ll have to provide those ourselves in the template.

Read more: [Working with Forms: Building a form in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django)

The reason you are not getting the `<form>` tag is because from a logical point of view a form validation can be handled anywhere in your application. That's why you need to specify the form tag explicitly with the target url (good to use [reverse(view_name)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)), method and other parameters.