# Django management form missing or tampered with - management form is in the template

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, formsets

I have a template with lots of forms on it, all wrapped in one form element. I have on MultiForm that is comprised of 4 regular forms, and two formsets. The formsets have been overridden to use custom formset classes.
I render the management forms in the templates, and can see the relevant info in the post.

For the formsets, I initialize the page with only one form visible.

When I try to submit the combined form I get the following error:

```
ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with
```

I have searched everywhere for the answer, and read about 15 posts on stack overflow with the same error, but none of the solutions seem to help.

The error page highlights the following line:

```
{{ beneficiaries.management_form }}
```

Template:

```
<form class='pension_form' id='implementation_form' action="{% url "confirmation_form" %}" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}

<ul>
{{ the_form.user_info.as_ul }}  
 </ul>
<ul>
{{ the_form.spouse_info.as_ul }}  
</ul>

 <div class='formset_container'> {{ children.management_form }}
 {% for form in children %}
    <div class='formset'><ul>{{ form.as_ul }}  </ul><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></a></div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
  <ul>
{{ the_form.employer_info.as_ul }}  
</ul>
  <ul>
<li>{{ the_form.beneficiary_general.WHO_BENEFITS }}</li>
</ul>
<div id='beneficiary_info_container' style='display:none;'>
<div class='formset_container'>
 {{ beneficiaries.management_form }}
{% for form in beneficiaries %}
<div class='formset' >
<ul>{{ form.as_ul }}</ul><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></a></div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<ul><li id='inheritance_order'>
{{ the_form.beneficiary_general.BENEFICIARIES_DIE.label_tag }}
{{ the_form.beneficiary_general.BENEFICIARIES_DIE }}
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<button class='btn btn-default main-btn'>{% trans "_Continue" %}
</form>
```

View:

```
def show_confirmation_form(request):
ChildFormSet = formset_factory(ChildInfo, formset=ChildInfoFormSet, 
        extra=14, can_delete=True)
BeneficiaryFormSet = formset_factory(BeneficiaryInfo, formset=BeneficiaryInfoFormSet, 
        extra=10, can_delete=True)
multi_form_prefix = 'main_form'
child_prefix = 'children_info'
beneficiary_prefix = 'beneficiary_info'
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ConfirmationForm(request.POST, prefix=multi_form_prefix)
    children_forms = ChildFormSet(request.POST, prefix=child_prefix)
    beneficary_forms = BeneficiaryFormSet(request.POST, 
        prefix=beneficiary_prefix)
    if form.is_valid():
            #not ready yet
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
else:
    form = ConfirmationForm(prefix=multi_form_prefix)
    children_forms = ChildFormSet(prefix=child_prefix)
    beneficary_forms = BeneficiaryFormSet(prefix=beneficiary_prefix)
context = {'the_form' : form, 'children' : children_forms, 
    'beneficiaries' : beneficary_forms}
return render(request, "confirmation_form.html", context)
```

Forms.py

```
class BeneficiaryInfo(forms.Form):
SHEM_PRATI_MUTAV = forms.CharField(label=_("First_Name"))
SHEM_MISHPACHA_MUTAV = forms.CharField(label=_("Last_Name"))
MISPAR_ZEHUT_MUTAV = forms.IntegerField(label=_("Mispar_Zehut"))
ACHUZ_HALUKA = forms.IntegerField(label=_("Percent_Allocate"))

class BeneficiaryInfoFormSet(BaseFormSet):
def clean(self):
    """
    Adds validation to check that no two links have the same anchor or URL
    and that all links have both an anchor and URL.
    """
    if any(self.errors):
        return

    teudot_zehut = []
    distribution_total = 0

    for form in self.forms:
        if form.cleaned_data:
            teudat_zehut = form.cleaned_data['MISPAR_ZEHUT_MUTAV']
            #allow empty forms.
            if teudat_zehut:
                if teudat_zehut in teudot_zehut:
                    form.add_error(None, 'No mutavim can share teudot_zehut')
            distribution_total += int(form.cleaned_data['ACHUZ_HALUKA'])
    if distribution_total != 100:
        form.add_error(None, 'Distribution Total must be 100')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django modelformset\_factory doesn't include actual forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324752/django-modelformset-factory-doesnt-include-actual-forms)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone runs into a similar problem:

The problem was the I only showed the formsets if a certain checkbox was checked, and the management form was in the hidden area. I moved it out of the div that was hidden and it worked perfectly.